# Sequence of tenses with while

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Are the sentences grammatically correct?

> He hadn't been cleaning Suzi's room while she was ill.
>
> He wasn't cleaning Suzi's room while she was ill.

PS: I think I should have added a request for context. Could you come up with contexts in which they can be used?

Comment: Is Suzi "her"? It would be clearer if you put Suzi first and the pronoun second.

Comment: actually "the he" is her husband

Comment: I'm asking about "her". Is that Suzi? Does this have the same meaning: "*He hadn't been cleaning **Suzi's** room while **she** was ill*"?

Comment: Yes. Though, it's a minor point who the "her" is.

Comment: It isn't a minor point; 'her' could be someone whose room Suzi normally cleaned, and 'he' hadn't been standing in for Suzi while she was unable to do it.

Comment: But how does it all concern the tenses?

Comment: @user1425 Because having unnatural structure in sentences makes it difficult to assess the naturalness of the whole sentence, even parts you're not asking about.

Answer (score 0):

As I know they are because with when while (that already emphasize simultaneous reference) you can ignore sequence of tenses

Comment: Your sentence isn't at all clear, Petro.